# Stack Overflow не открывается с Теле2

Tags: обсуждение

Имею IP 176.59.8.239, сайты Stack Overflow (любые) успешно пингуются, но попытки подключиться к порту 80 или 443 напрочь игнорируются, как будто на меня прописали DROP в iptables.

Утром ещё открывался, днём уже нет.

Роскомнадзором вроде бы не заблокировано (ну или, может, заблокировали вот только что, не знаю).

Через прокси/VPN/оперу-турбо открывается, через другого интернет-провайдера тоже открывается (иначе бы я это не писал, хех).

Такие дела. Если у кого-то ещё есть Tele2, скажите, работает ли у вас?

---

Трассировка по ICMP с Теле2 (пинги работают, поэтому и трассировка есть):

```html
$ sudo traceroute --icmp ru.stackoverflow.com
traceroute to ru.stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  10.255.128.0 (10.255.128.0)  175.243 ms  175.231 ms  178.592 ms
 3  10.3.246.81 (10.3.246.81)  73.438 ms  73.564 ms  75.053 ms
 4  10.226.6.66 (10.226.6.66)  75.033 ms  78.400 ms  83.267 ms
 5  10.226.8.5 (10.226.8.5)  79.263 ms  79.378 ms  79.372 ms
 6  10.226.8.14 (10.226.8.14)  90.987 ms  29.733 ms  41.602 ms
 7  10.226.6.65 (10.226.6.65)  35.905 ms  35.878 ms  36.694 ms
 8  217.169.83.4 (217.169.83.4)  35.811 ms  35.806 ms  38.307 ms
 9  85.112.123.0 (85.112.123.0)  41.707 ms  37.194 ms  34.313 ms
10  rascom.inet2.net (85.112.122.13)  36.340 ms  53.936 ms  49.809 ms
11  80-64-100-102.rascom.as20764.net (80.64.100.102)  49.864 ms  52.382 ms  53.698 ms
12  be4338.204.ccr21.sto01.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.168.137)  57.157 ms  53.418 ms  50.819 ms
13  149.6.168.70 (149.6.168.70)  45.670 ms  47.433 ms  48.078 ms
14  151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69)  63.922 ms  66.006 ms  63.449 ms
```

Трассировка по TCP к порту 80 с Теле2 (уже не работает):

```html
$ sudo traceroute --tcp -p 80 ru.stackoverflow.com
traceroute to ru.stackoverflow.com (151.101.129.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  10.255.128.0 (10.255.128.0)  39.062 ms  241.558 ms  241.649 ms
 3  10.3.246.81 (10.3.246.81)  41.511 ms  49.015 ms  52.114 ms
 4  10.226.6.66 (10.226.6.66)  57.477 ms  57.460 ms  63.073 ms
 5  10.226.8.5 (10.226.8.5)  57.288 ms  63.035 ms  64.890 ms
 6  10.226.8.14 (10.226.8.14)  68.977 ms  30.041 ms  29.943 ms
 7  10.226.6.65 (10.226.6.65)  34.145 ms  31.133 ms  35.649 ms
 8  217.169.83.4 (217.169.83.4)  29.752 ms  29.715 ms  34.141 ms
 9  85.112.123.0 (85.112.123.0)  39.724 ms  37.278 ms  35.775 ms
10  rascom.inet2.net (85.112.122.13)  39.834 ms  35.769 ms  35.647 ms
11  80-64-100-102.rascom.as20764.net (80.64.100.102)  49.626 ms  45.553 ms  47.516 ms
12  be4338.204.ccr21.sto01.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.168.137)  45.846 ms  47.573 ms  49.799 ms
13  149.6.168.46 (149.6.168.46)  50.036 ms 149.6.168.54 (149.6.168.54)  47.287 ms 149.6.168.46 (149.6.168.46)  47.564 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Трассировка по ICMP с рандомного интернет-провайдера:

```html
$ sudo traceroute --icmp ru.stackoverflow.com
traceroute to ru.stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.280 ms  0.589 ms  0.744 ms
 2  94.19.78.1.pool.sknt.ru (94.19.78.1)  3.588 ms  3.595 ms  3.596 ms
 3  Router.sknt.ru (93.100.0.132)  1.765 ms  1.910 ms  2.307 ms
 4  Router.sknt.ru (93.100.0.164)  1.928 ms  2.278 ms  2.286 ms
 5  ae8.RT.KM.SPB.RU.retn.net (87.245.252.157)  1.678 ms  1.687 ms  1.707 ms
 6  ae3-8.RT.TC2.AMS.NL.retn.net (87.245.233.17)  34.511 ms  33.941 ms  33.872 ms
 7  80.249.212.183 (80.249.212.183)  32.867 ms  32.901 ms  32.900 ms
 8  151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69)  32.805 ms  32.854 ms  32.831 ms
```

Трассировка по TCP к порту 80 с рандомного интернет-провайдера (рабочая):

```html
$ sudo traceroute --tcp -p 80 ru.stackoverflow.com
traceroute to ru.stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.275 ms  0.507 ms  0.634 ms
 2  94.19.78.1.pool.sknt.ru (94.19.78.1)  4.131 ms  4.127 ms  4.120 ms
 3  * * *
 4  Router.sknt.ru (93.100.0.164)  3.317 ms  3.293 ms  3.290 ms
 5  ae8.RT.KM.SPB.RU.retn.net (87.245.252.157)  2.965 ms  2.998 ms  3.032 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  172.31.4.16 (172.31.4.16)  1.632 ms  1.985 ms  2.131 ms
 9  ae3-8.RT.TC2.AMS.NL.retn.net (87.245.233.17)  35.180 ms  35.131 ms  35.138 ms
10  80.249.212.183 (80.249.212.183)  33.673 ms 80.249.212.184 (80.249.212.184)  33.737 ms 80.249.212.183 (80.249.212.183)  33.102 ms
11  151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69)  33.037 ms  33.167 ms  34.750 ms
```

Comment: Их там Ростелеком же покупает. Совпадение? (¬‿¬ )

Comment: день за днем, железный занавес над Россией накрывается...

Comment: Написал ответ, что стало открываться, но сейчас опять не открывается, пришлось удалить)

Comment: Пока лежал телефон в кармане, запущенный в фоне телнет разок подключился, а потом опять перестал подключаться. Где-то кого-то глючит. // Пробовал перебрать все IP-адреса из A-записей DNS - при мне телнет ни к одному не подключался

Comment: @Suvitruf с ростелекома открывается

Comment: теле2 Вологда. Полет нормальный

Comment: В таком случае уточню, что я в Петербурге

Comment: Проверил с чужого телефона с другой SIM-картой — тоже не открывается

Comment: Подтверждаю, в СПб через Теле2 не открывается.

Comment: В нижнем новгороде норм

Comment: @andreymal, В порядке эксперимента рекомендую ещё купить и другой телефон :) все остальное вы уже опробовали..

Comment: Ростовская область, г. Волгодонск не открывается.... думаю стоит мониторить базы с ip адресами.

Comment: У меня (в СПБ) тоже не работало (иногда один push умудрялся пролезть), переписывался с оператором - посоветовали обратиться к владельцам сайта, заработало нормально днем 31.03.2019

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а у меня до сих пор не работает (впрочем, я ни к кому не обращался)

Comment: @andreymal в приложении теле2 есть чат с оператором... я им воспользовался

Comment: @andreymal сегодня днем еще работало... сейчас опять не пашет только что проверил

Comment: По состоянию на сейчас снова открывается

Comment: Всё ещё открывается. Или мне везёт попадать на незабаненные IP, или проблема действительно решилась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последние несколько дней стабильно открывается. Но что это было, до сих пор непонятно

Comment: Веерные блокировки, скорее всего.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ блокировки обычно видно [где-то тут](http://заблокировано-в.рф/?host=ru.stackoverflow.com), но в данном случае их было не очень видно

Comment: @andreymal тут только нужно знать, как часто обновляется база....